# Xpages not fetching file from web service

Tags: javascript, xpages

I am using Xpages for show data that I recieved through Web service.
Now the problem is that for some unknown reason, instead of URL to the source page, the source html code is sent. Now since it's large to be saved in database, I use the SSJS to send the ID to agent that gets that source and exports it to the folder on server.

Now i have tried using client side javascript to open the file

```
window.open("http://192.168.1.220/EXPORT/563617.html");
```

and it returns error 404

How can i get the file and open it or download from server?

Comment: If it returns 404, it's clearly not the right URL ?

Comment: If you plug that URL into your web browser's address, does it return what you expect? Also, if you can remote into the server you're running your Domino server from (assuming separate OS), can you confirm it has visibility of that IP and page?

Comment: I don't get it - "instead of URL ... source html code is sent" - please, add more details. The 404 problem can be solved by saving to domino/html directory.

Comment: The URL is correct because the test.nsf where the Xpage is created is in EXPORT/test.nsf.

"instead of URL ... source html code is sent" thtat's what i get from web servis a complete html that's exported into folder on domino server. Now i need to open it or download from server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your question the way that you receive an HTML page from web service and want to show it in browser client. You don't need to save it as an .html file. Instead, show the HTML content in a computed field in your XPage. Set the property `escape="false"` so it will interprete your HTML as HTML:

```
<xp:text
    escape="false"
    id="computedField2"
    value="#{javascript: ... call web service ... return yourHTMLString}">
</xp:text>
```

This way you don't need to save the HTML string in your database neither.

If the HTML is really a complete page then put the computed field into an iFrame or reduce the HTML by head and footer so it "fits" into the rendered XPage.